# How to update of Azure Table Storage Entity with ETag

Tags: python, multithreading, azure, azure-functions, azure-table-storage

**Overview**: When I upload blob in blob storage under container/productID(folder)/blobName, then event-subscription saves this event in the storage queue. After that azure function polls this event and does the following:

> 1- read from the corresponding table the current count property (how
> many blobs are stored under productID(folder)) with the etag
>
> 2- increase the count + 1
>
> 3- write it back in the corresponding table, if ETag is matched, then the field count will be increased, otherwise throws an error. if err is thrown, sleep while and go to step 1 (while loop)
>
> 4- if property field successful increased, then return

**scenario**: trying to upload five items to blob storage

**Expectation**: the count property in table storage stores 5.

**problem**: after inserting the first four items successful, the code get in an infinite loop for inserting the fifth item, and the count property increased forever. why that could happen, I don't have any ideas. any ideas from you will be good

```
#more code
        header_etag = "random-etag"
        response_etag = "random-response"
        while(response_etag != header_etag):
            sleep(random.random())  # sleep between 0 and 1 second.
            header = table_service.get_entity_table(
                client_table, client_table, client_product)
            new_count = header['Count'] + 1
            entity_product = create_product_entity(
                client_table, client_product, new_count, client_image_table)
            header_etag = header['etag']
            try:    
                response_etag = table_service1.merge_entity(client_table, entity_product,
                                                            if_match=header_etag)
            except:
                logging.info("race condition detected")
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try implementing your parameters and logic in while loop with below code:

```
val = 0 # Initial value as zero
success = False
    while True:
        val  = val + 1 #incrementing
        CheckValidations = input(‘Check’) #add validations
        if CheckValidations == "abc123":
            success = True # this will allow the loop
            break
        if val > 5:
            break
        print("Please Try Again")
if success == True:
print("Welcome!")
```

Also check for the below .py file from Azure Python SDK documentation where we have a clear function for update, merge and insert for entities in table storage

[azure-sdk-for-python/sample_update_upsert_merge_entities.py at main · Azure/azure-sdk-for-python (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure/azure-sdk-for-python/blob/main/sdk/tables/azure-data-tables/samples/sample_update_upsert_merge_entities.py)

Refer to [Microsoft documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/table/how-to-use-python#add-an-entity-to-a-table) to check how can we pass exact parameters for create entity.

For more insight on table samples check Azure samples

[storage-table-python-getting-started/table_basic_samples.py at master · Azure-Samples/storage-table-python-getting-started (github.com)](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/storage-table-python-getting-started/blob/master/table_basic_samples.py)